# MySQL Order By alternate values

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having trouble in MySQL query Order By.

First I have a table(tbl_records) that contains 10000+ records. This table has a primary key called **rec_id** and a foreign key **rec_f_id**.

**rec_f_id** has only two kinds of value (555, 666).

Now my problem is how can I gather the records on the table that orders in alternate value of **rec_f_id**.

Eg

Below is a dummy tbl records

```
 | rec_id   |   rec_f_id |
 |2         |666         |
 |3         |555         |
 |7         |555         |
 |8         |666         |
 |9         |555         |
 |12        |666         |
 |25        |555         |
 |31        |555         |
 |84        |666         |
 |89        |555         |
 |91        |555         |
 |92        |666         |
 |113       |666         |
 |118       |666         |
 |125       |555         |
 |132       |555         |
 |170       |555         |
 |184       |666         |


 SELECT * FROM tbl_records ORDER BY FIELD(rec_f_id, 555, 666) LIMIT 100;
```

The above query only returns record with rec_f_id = 555.
What I want to have is

```
 | rec_id   |   rec_f_id |
 |31        |555         |
 |12        |666         |
 |3         |555         |
 |8         |666         |
 |25        |555         |
 |2         |666         |
 |7         |555         |
 |84        |666         |
 |9         |555         |

 ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just order by `rec_id`?  Can you supply real sample data?

Comment: why don't you order by rec_id only?

Comment: @user2480596 the record above is only a dummy record.

Comment: @sephoy08 -- what determines the ordering of the results now?

Comment: @user2480596 - ok, i changed the sample result i want to achieved. The rec_id can have rec_f_id without pattern

Comment: @user2480596 - well basically i want to get the records in alternate pattern based on the rec_f_id value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using `user-defined variables`.  Basically it creates a `Row Number` per Group, and then orders by it along with the `rec_f_id` field:

```
SELECT rec_id, rec_f_id
FROM (
  SELECT rec_id, rec_f_id,
    @rn:=IF(@prev=rec_f_id,@rn+1,1) rn,
    @prev:=rec_f_id
  FROM tbl_records
    JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0, @prev:=0) t
  ORDER BY rec_f_id
  ) t
ORDER BY rn, rec_f_id
```

- [Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd80d/1)

Comment: Hi Thank you This is great it absolutely cater my problem. The only down side is that, the query is taking too long.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_records
WHERE rec_f_id in (555,666) 
ORDER BY rec_id, rec_f_id,
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Hi , sorry this is not what i meant. I  want to get the records in alternate rows depending on the value of rec_f_id . rec_id does not pattern with this sequence.