# Order by alternating groups of results (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3)

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a big table of products and we want to do a very custom ordering + pagination on
it. We might get 2 or 3 million products, all categorized, biggest category would contain
200k products. The products come from a lot of other sites (150+). If we leave the
ordering be there's a very big chance page 1, 2 and 3 contain products from (big) site x
only. We want to give other sites a chance to, so we need to display products like this:

```
Product 1 (site 1)
Product 256 (site 2)
Product 956 (site 3)
...................
Product x (site 150)
Product 879 (site 1)
Product 135 (site 2)
Product 5647 (site 3)
...................
Product y (site 150)
```

How it possible order like this using elasticsearch?

Comment: Ignoring Elasticsearch, how would you expect that to work?

Comment: There is solution for mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862522/mysql-order-by-alternate-values

Comment: It is also possible with PostgreSQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207867/alternate-results-with-order-by-clause